# AngularJS: Get data with $http and add it to module's constants

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, angularjs, http

I want to achieve a situtation where once my module is loaded it call the server for some data and than put it in a conatant.

I tried this:

```
mymodule.constant('value', function($http) {
    $http.post('/path/to/api').success(function (response) {
       return(response);
    }).error(function (response) {

    });
});;
```

But obviously I'm missing something,
Thanks

Comment: may be you are adding something extra...extra ; in the end

Comment: Heh, no no it's not it. the extra was only here in the topic

Comment: is this copied from your real code? because you return `respons` instead of `response`

Comment: @yarons Thank you for noticing, it's a copy with some naming changes. logic remain the same

Comment: what exactly do you get? do you ever reach the success/fail functions?

Comment: @yarons nope, the code isnt executed

Comment: You're misusing angular 'constant' service and specifically misusing $http. I think what you're looking for is creating a service with a method that receives a promise with the response from the server.